# Redirect ApiController based on URI string match

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Suppose I have a REST endpoint like https://localhost:5000/api/animals/cat/1 and I wish to redirect all the URI which contains `/animals`. Is there a way in ASP .Net Core where I can detect in the initial stage itself, if the call contains the string `animals` and then modify that URI to return a different path with few headers added?

Comment: You can use [Route Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-route-constraints)

Answer (score 4):

You can use middle ware in .net core:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("animals"))
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("/animals/category-animal");

        return _next(httpContext);
    }
}
// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.

    public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
        }

}
```

Add app.UseMyMiddleware() before app.UseMvc() in startup class.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes allow for this. Say your controller is called `GetAnimal` for example

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("animals/{name}/{id}")]
public ActionResult GetAnimal(string name, int id)
{

    // add headers and redirect

}
```

Comment: Should be `[Route("api/animals/{name}/{id}")]`. Plus 1!

Comment: Correct, so long as the "api" part isn't default on the route for the class itself, as it tends to be from the MVC templates.

Answer (score 1):

Check this feature of Routing in asp.net core:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#parameter-transformer-reference